# How to get Spring Boot active profiles name(s) in velocity template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

Is there any way to get the active profile name(s) from velocity template without having to pass the parameter through ModelView object of the mvc controller on a Spring Boot application?

I used the `-Dspring.profiles.active=profilename` JVM parameter to activate my profile.

Using Thymeleaf I can access active profile name(s) using a built-in `@environment.acceptsProfiles('production')` method. Is there any built-in way to do the same in velocity templates?